# Trigger on UPDATE OF a particular column Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE regions (
    region_id number NOT NULL,
    region_name varchar2(25) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT reg_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (region_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_history
(
  operation character varying(120) NOT NULL ,
  table_name character varying(120) NOT NULL ,
  column_name character varying(120) NOT NULL, 
  old_value character varying(120),
  new_value character varying(120)
 );
 
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger regions_audit
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON regions
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
BEGIN
  for c in (SELECT table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns ) loop
    if updating(c.column_name ) then
      INSERT INTO tbl_history (operation,table_name, column_name, old_value, new_value) 
                        VALUES('Update',c.table_name,c.column_name,:old.column_name,:new.column_name);
    end if;
  end loop;

END;
/
```

Trigger on UPDATE OF a Dynamic column?
result is:
operation   table_name      column_name      old_value        new_value_
UPDATE      regions         region_name      Asia             Europe
UPDATE      regions         region_id        5                4

Comment: There is no question here.  Format your code, take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That's in vain, you can't create "generic" trigger which would work on any table. In Oracle, triggers are *anchored* to their tables, so code which shows how to do it might be

```
SQL> create or replace trigger regions_audit
  2    before insert or delete or update on regions
  3    for each row
  4    enable
  5  declare
  6  begin
  7    if updating then
  8      insert into tbl_history
  9        (operation, table_name, column_name, old_value, new_value)
 10         values
 11         ('Update', 'regions', 'region_name', :old.region_name,:new.region_name);
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

In other words: table and column name are *static*; table name is `regions` as that's the table that trigger is based on. Column name is `region_name` as you really shouldn't be modifying primary key column's value. Old and new values are then also related to `region_name`.

As of other operations (deleting, inserting), you'd do similarly.